# Is there a way to know how many applications there is in a card using EMV?

Tags: emv

I'm developing an application for a Point-Of-Sale, and there is a step in the process where I need to send the gateway an information saying if the card is Credit only, debit only or has both applications in it. Is there an EMV tag or something similar that I can use to find out this information?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Terminals have two ways to build the Candidate List of applications:

1. **Exhaustive search of known Application Identifiers (AID):** Terminals have a list of supported AIDs (based on the brands and products they support) and will simply issue a `SELECT` for each AID in the list; if successful, the AID is added to the candidate list.
2. **Optionally, they may support the PSE method:** This involves reading a file in the card to see what applications are offered by the card. Please note:

   - The PSE is optional for cards on the contact interface; I believe the PPSE is mandatory on the contactless interface.
   - There could be proprietary/domestic payment applications not listed in the (P)PSE.